# Excel VBA order/grouping of "Call"

Tags: excel, call, wait, vba

Probably not the best title, but it will be better with this exemple.

Here's a function inside a `userform` of a `checkbox`. I was trying to change the font to `bold` *before* the call to `SelectAlldtList`(which takes a few seconds to do).

What is happening is that the font doesn't change until *after* the `SelectAlldtList` is finished.

```
Private Sub CheckBoxAllDirectionTerritoriale_Click()
    If Me.CheckBoxAllDirectionTerritoriale.Value = True Then
        CheckBoxAllDirectionTerritoriale.Font.Bold = True
        Call SelectAlldtList
    Else
        CheckBoxAllDirectionTerritoriale.Font.Bold = False
        Call UnselectAlldtList
    End If
End Sub
```

If I add a `Wait` of **6** milliseconds, the behavior is the one I want. 
If I add a `Wait` of **5** milliseconds, the behavior is the same as without the `Wait` at all.

```
Private Sub CheckBoxAllDirectionTerritoriale_Click()
    If Me.CheckBoxAllDirectionTerritoriale.Value = True Then
        CheckBoxAllDirectionTerritoriale.Font.Bold = True
        Application.Wait (Now + 0.000006)
        Call SelectAlldtList
    Else
        CheckBoxAllDirectionTerritoriale.Font.Bold = False
        Application.Wait (Now + 0.000006)
        Call UnselectAlldtList
    End If
End Sub
```

Why is that? Is it something like without the `Wait`, `SelectAlldtList` is called before having time to `bold` and taking all the ressources?

While I'm at it, would there be a better way to do this? Some kind of synchronization?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very experienced with what you have here, but I had a somewhat similar problem with a macro that zipped files and also needed a wait added to work correctly. Maybe what helped me could help you. Here's what I used to sync it:

```
Do Until Object1.Namespace(Variant1).items.Count = 1
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
Loop
```

and here's how you might apply it (untested):

```
Private Sub CheckBoxAllDirectionTerritoriale_Click()
    If Me.CheckBoxAllDirectionTerritoriale.Value = True Then
        CheckBoxAllDirectionTerritoriale.Font.Bold = True
        Do Until CheckBoxAllDirectionTerritoriale.Font.Bold = True
            Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001)
        Loop
        Call SelectAlldtList
    Else
        CheckBoxAllDirectionTerritoriale.Font.Bold = False
        Do Until CheckBoxAllDirectionTerritoriale.Font.Bold = False
            Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001)
        Loop
        Call UnselectAlldtList
    End If
End Sub
```

I set it for one millisecond, but if you get some error with it being partially bolded or whatever, you might want to increase it to two. Note that you will still probably end up having the slight delay, but this way if it's 5, 7, etc. milliseconds you'll still be covered, I think.

Comment: Well it doesn't work for my situation, the code **never** enters the `Do Until`

Comment: Weird, it just skips straight over it into the `Call` line? Btw, did you know you don't need the word `Call` anymore, you can just put the function name? Sorry I couldn't be of more help.